# Whats the error in below code ? not getting expected output

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Given an array of integers and an integer k, find out whether there are two distinct indices i and j in the array such that nums[i] = nums[j] and the absolute difference between i and j is at most k.

Example 1:
Input: nums = [1,2,3,1], k = 3
Output: true

Example 2:
Input: nums = [1,0,1,1], k = 1
Output: true

```scala
object Solution {
  def containsNearbyDuplicate(nums: Array[Int], k: Int): Boolean = { 
    for (i <- 0 until nums.length - 2) {
       for (j <- i until nums.length - 1) {
         if (nums(i) == nums(j) && (j - i == k)) return true
       }
    }
    return false
  }
}
```

Your input
[1,2,3,1]
3
Output
false
Expected
true

Comment: You are not computing the absolute difference between `j` and `i`; also such difference does not need to be equal to `k` just at most `k`

Comment: Here is a functional version of the algorithm: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/hFziNk8YToS7ZgQcr0887w/1

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're evaluating the full length of the inner list.

As written, `j` will never equal `3`.

I think if you make your inner loop read `for (j <- i until nums.length)` that should work.

Probably want to fix the outer loop too. Otherwise, `i` will never reach the value of 3 stored in your array.

Using until will exclude, so if you use `i <- 0 until nums.length -1` where length is 3, then the value of `i` will be 0, 1, 2 and end.

If you want to subtract - 1 because it feels easier or makes more sense to you, then you probably want to use `i <- 0 to nums.length - 1`.

Otherwise, `i <-0 until nums.length` will result in the value of `i` being 0, 1, 2, 3 as it iterates through the for loop.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is functional, efficient as O(n) instead of O(n^2) and fixes a bug(`i != j`). You should always have a negative case too when testing ;)

```
import math.{min, max}
def containsNearbyDuplicate(nums: Array[Int])(k: Int): Boolean = {
  val indexesToCheck = for {
    i <- 0 until nums.length
    j <- max(0, i - k) to min(nums.length - 1, i + k)
    if i != j
  } yield (i, j)
  indexesToCheck.exists {case (i, j) => nums(i) == nums(j)}
}

containsNearbyDuplicate(nums = Array(1, 2, 3, 1, 5))(k = 3)
containsNearbyDuplicate(nums = Array(1, 2, 3, 1, 5))(k = 2)
containsNearbyDuplicate(nums = Array(1, 0, 1, 1, 5))(k = 1)
```